# How to find the CUSTOM_DIMENSION_KEY_ID in GAM API

Tags: java, api, google-ad-manager

I'm trying to run a report with custom fields. For that I need to provide Custom field id and Custom dimension key id in the code. I got the custom field id by running the custom field service. But I'm not sure how will I get the Custom dimension key id.

Below is the code snippet :

```
public class Report_CustomFields {

  private static class RunReportWithCustomFieldsParams extends CodeSampleParams {
    @Parameter(
        names = ArgumentNames.CUSTOM_FIELD_ID,
        required = true,
        description = "The ID of the custom field to include in the report.")
    private Long customFieldId;

    @Parameter(
        names = ArgumentNames.CUSTOM_DIMENSION_KEY_ID,
        required = true,
        description = "The ID of the custom key field to include as a Dimension in the report.")
    private Long customDimensionKeyId;
  }
```

I have checked the documentation , I could find something like this .

> customDimensionKeyIds xsd:long[]
>
> The list of custom dimension custom targeting key IDs being requested
> in this report. This will include dimensions in the form of
> TOP_LEVEL_DIMENSION_KEY[id]_ID and TOP_LEVEL_DIMENSION_KEY[id]_VALUE
> where ID is the ID of the custom targeting value and VALUE is the
> name.
>
> To add IDs, you must include Dimension.CUSTOM_DIMENSION in dimensions,
> and specify a non-empty list of custom targeting key IDs. The order of
> cusotm dimension columns in the report correspond to the place of
> Dimension.CUSTOM_DIMENSION in dimensions. For example, if dimensions
> contains the following dimensions in the order:
> Dimension.ADVERTISER_NAME, Dimension.CUSTOM_DIMENSION and
> Dimension.COUNTRY_NAME, and customCriteriaCustomTargetingKeyIds
> contains the following IDs in the order: 1001 and 1002. The order of
> dimensions in the report will be: Dimension.ADVERTISER_NAME,
> Dimension.TOP_LEVEL_DIMENSION_KEY[1001]_VALUE,
> Dimension.TOP_LEVEL_DIMENSION_KEY[1002]_VALUE, Dimension.COUNTRY_NAME,
> Dimension.ADVERTISER_ID, Dimension.TOP_LEVEL_DIMENSION_KEY[1001]_ID,
> Dimension.TOP_LEVEL_DIMENSION_KEY[1002]_ID,
> Dimension.COUNTRY_CRITERIA_ID.

But I dont understand from where can I get the dimension key id , I could find only the field id so far. Can some one help please .

Comment: @rabsom Here we get the id of Custom trageting values. What I'm looking for is a custom field , which appears in Admin->GlobalSettings->Custom Fields.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to retrieve its id through the Google Ad Manager user interface :

1. log in
2. go to admin > global settings > custom fields
3. select an entry
4. get the id from the URL

Here is a screenshot [image]

Comment: Here we get the id of Custom trageting values. What I'm looking for is a custom field , which appears in Admin->GlobalSettings->Custom Fields.

Comment: Hi Lakshmi, i edited my answer so you can get the custom field id

Comment: Yeah I tried this as well and got this Custom field ID running the custom field service but as per the GAM api documentation there is one Custom dimension key id as well which I didnt get a clue yet. I could only find this customfield id. 

" CUSTOM_DIMENSION
Breaks down reporting data by the CustomTargetingKeys marked as dimensions in inventory key-values setup. To use this dimension, a list of custom targeting key IDs must be specified in ReportQuery.customDimensionKeyIds. "